# Difference between plots in IDL

Tags: plot, idl, array-difference

I'm working with two plots of density as a function of distance on IDL. What I'd like to do with them is convert them into plots of distance as a function of density and plot their difference, in order to obtain the shift in distance as a function of density. The issue I'm having is that one of the equations for density as a function of distance is non invertible.
Any idea on what I could do to overcome this problem?
Thanks in advance. Here are the tewo plots that I'm trying to invert and take the difference of.

```
lowe = ALOG10(10.)
  uppe = ALOG10(170.)
  re = DINDGEN(100)*(uppe - lowe)/(100 - 1L) + lowe
  r = 10^(re)

  loweB = ALOG10(10.)
  uppeB = ALOG10(170.)
  reB = DINDGEN(100)*(uppeB - loweB)/(100 - 1L) + loweB
  rB = 10^(reB)

pl = plot(r,density_r(r), /XLOG, /YLOG)
plB = plot(r,freq_ratB(r), /OVERPLOT, /XLOG, /YLOG)  

end

FUNCTION density_r, r
  
  return, 4.8e9/r^14 + 3e8/r^6 + 1.4e6/r^2.3
END

 FUNCTION freq_ratB, r
  
  return, 10.*(r/215.)^(-2.8)
END
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to plot distance as a function of density — just change the order of the arguments to `plot`, i.e.:

```
p_r = plot(density_r(r), r, /xlog, /ylog)
plB_r = plot(freq_ratB(r), r, /overplot, /xlog, /ylot)
```

But to subtract the two plots, the x-coordinates of your difference plot must be the same for the two operands of the difference. You can write an equation to invert one of your functions:

```
; intvert freq_ratB
function r_freq_ratB, density
  compile_opt strictarr

  return, 215.0 * exp((alog(density) - log(10.0)) / (-2.8))
end
```

So then you can plot the difference:

```
p_difference = plot(density, r - r_freq_ratB(density))
```

If you couldn't invert one of your functions, e.g., you were plotting observational data, then you would have to interpolate.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was really helpful!